# Multiline string literal parsing

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have tried the following in Python's Interactive console:

```
>>> """"string"""
'"string'
>>> """"string""""
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I expect the latter case `""""string""""` to return `'"string"'` because I have three quotes at the start and three quotes at the end. How does Python interpret it?

Comment: Because Python parses from left to right; it does not look for the end of a string from right to left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sees the triple-quoted string `""""string"""`, followed by a non-triple-quoted string that doesn't complete by EOL, `"`.

The [tokenize](http://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) module can show you what it's doing:

```
s = '""""string""""'
g = tokenize.generate_tokens(io.StringIO(s).readline)
t = list(g)
print(t)
```

This prints a STRING token with `'""""string"""'`, then an ERRORTOKEN token with `'"'`.

In general, the best way of answering any question like this when you can't figure out how to interpret [the grammar](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) (I assume you looked at the grammar first?) is to use tokenize, ast, and friends.

Answer (score 1):

Python is interpreting it as:

```
 """"string""" "                                                                                                                   "
#^^^These three " to start the string literal. The next one counts in the string.
#The three last ones after the last one are counted as the end.
```

Notice the straying `"`.

You can just do:

```
'''"string"'''
```